# Kindle Oasis: increase contrast for non-black text and images

Tags: kindle, usability

I have a Kindle Oasis where the text and image contrast is normally great.

But now I'm reading a book (ironically it's [Universal Principles of Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A3T5UO4)) that has hundreds of images which are followed by text descriptions.

Unfortunately, all the images and their descriptions are not black — they're in a lighter gray color that is hard to read due to the lack of contrast.

Interestingly, when I make a text selection or while zooming/moving an image, the color is temporarily set to the normal black color.

My question is — can I force Kindle to always render text and images in black or somehow specify the minimum contrast?

Comment: That is hilarious. :D I hope you emailed the authors.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?